# Understanding Meta classes in python

Tags: python, python-3.6, metaclass

I am trying to learn `metaclasses` in python, from my research i found a example like follow.

i have a `Base` and `Derived` classes like follow

```
class Base():
    def foo(self):
        return self.bar() 

class Derived(Base):
    def foo2(self):
        return "i am foo2"
```

now, when i want to make sure that whoever extending `Base` class, must need to implement `bar()` method, so i created the meta class to hook the constuction of derived class,so now `Base` class looks like follow with `BaseMeta` meta class.

```
class BaseMeta(type):
  def __new__(cls, name, bases, body):
    if not "bar" in body:
      raise TypeError("bar not implemented")
    return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, body)

class Base(metaclass=BaseMeta):
   def foo(self):
        return self.bar()
```

The problem is when i get looks into body it returns 2 records for `Base` and `Derived` class,  like follow.

```
 {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Base', 'foo': <function 
 Base.foo at 0x7ffbaae436a8>}
 {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Derived', 'bar': <function 
 Derived.bar at 0x7ffbaae437b8>}
```

my code in `__new__` breaks since `Base` not have  `bar`, but i want to check only in the Derived class so i rewrite my `metaclass` like follow.

```
def __new__(cls, name, bases, body):
    if name !="Base" and not "bar" in body:
      raise TypeError("bar not implemented")
    return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, body)
```

I am checking `name != Base` in my `__new__` method.

> Is that the right way to do it or we can use some other best way?

Comment: fyi, what you are talking about is not a metaclass but a baseclass. [Metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python) has a very specific meaning and refers to something completely different.

Comment: We can also use `metaclass` to achieve this right?

Comment: Theoretically, I am sure. But metaclasses are intended to achieve something different called *class alteration*. Sorry that I am so vague, but I don't understand their use very well myself and just trust the top-voted answer from the question I linked which says that [99% of the time you need class alteration, you are better off using \[monkey patching or decorators\]. But 98% of the time, you don't need class alteration at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/962190) and go about my day ignoring that metaclasses exist.

Comment: got it, Actually i followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKPlPJyQrt4), video link but thanks for extra notes

Comment: That looks interesting, I'll try to have a look and get back if it turns out that I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Note that you could implement [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) to verify assertions about a child without defining a metaclass.

Comment: @chepner exactly `__init_subclass__` is an alternative to metaclass in python. `__builtclass__` also one more option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `abc` module in the stdlib, which has tools for doing exactly this.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html

```
import abc

class Base(abc.ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
         pass

class Derived(Base):
    pass

# This will raise an error because foo is not implemented
# >>> Derived() 
# TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Derived with abstract methods bar
```

Another strategy would be to have a `bar` method on your Base class that raises a NotImplementedError.  The main difference is that no error is raised until you actually call something that requires `bar`. e.g.

```
class Base():
    def foo(self):
        return self.bar() 

    def bar(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: I want to enforce constraint for `derived` class without implementing `bar` method in my `Base` class, and i am confused about example 1, i think it enforce `foo` right? but i need to enforce `bar()`

Comment: To enforce `bar` for a derived class, declare an abstract method on your base class for that method.  Edited response to reflect this.